# how to use python functions to use input to loop numbers and Increment or decrement by third number

Tags: python

1) Ask the user for 3 numbers

2) Using a loop,

a) Start from the first number

b) End at the second number (inclusive)

c) Increment or decrement by the third number.

d) Output the number AND the cubed value of the number

i have tried to create a function that allows a user to input 3 numbers and make a loop to go through the numbers but im not sure how to go about the rest of the parts of the question.

```
def sum1(): print("enter a value")

sum1(); a = int(input())

sum1(); b = int(input())

sum1(); c = int(input())

for x in range(a,b,c): print(a,b,c)
```

> ```
> Input
> First number : 1, second number: 11, third number: 3
> Output
> 1 cubed is 1
> 4 cubed is 64
> 7 cubed is 343
> 10 cubed is 1000
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python `range` takes an argument to add step to the range.

```
for x in range(1, 12, 3):
```

will iterate over numbers from 1 through 12 (exclusive) with an increment of 3.

**Code**:

```
def sum1():   
    a, b, c = map(int, input("Enter values separated by space: ").split())
    for x in range(a, b+1, c):
        print(f'{x} cubed is {x**3}')

sum1()

# 1 cubed is 1
# 4 cubed is 64
# 7 cubed is 343
# 10 cubed is 1000
```

Comment: Thanks! umm what if we didnt know the 3 numbers that the user would select how would i go about doing that.

Comment: See my last code. It asks for user input. User can give 3 numbers separated by space.